# How to install qt add-in (for Qt 4x) for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, qt4

How to install qt add-in (for Qt 4x) for Visual Studio 2012?
Installator told that there are no supported version on Visual studio is installed.

UPDATE:

Exact msvs **2012**, exact Qt Addin **1.1.xxx** (not 1.2.xxx)

Comment: Related question, but has only a workaround - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221812/is-it-possible-to-work-qt4-projects-in-visual-studio-2012-using-add-ins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18697762/2461476) indicates that it is possible with Qt VS Add-in 1.2.2, though there are some limitations to its support of Qt 4.x.  As far as full-blown support for Qt 4.x in VS 2012, I'm afraid that it may not be possible.

If you really need this support, I'd suggest requesting it via the Qt Project [forums](https://qt-project.org/forums) or their [JIRA bug tracking system](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: I asked in qt forums, but still no answer. And I added comment with link, that you provided. I think that there are no serios restrictions to make Qt Addin work with 2012 - thats why I asked for help (with bounty).

Comment: While there may be no serious _technical_ reasons that Qt4 couldn't work with VS2012, the people in charge of Qt probably did make a _business_ decision to not spend the time and money on providing support for an older version of Qt on a bleeding-edge compiler.  As I said, you can file a bug, but things with Qt are never fast, so don't necessarily expect an immediate response from them.  The answer I linked to provides you with _some_ Qt4 functionality, but there is not fully-fledged Qt4 VS Add-in for VS2012.