# Cannot find ui_chatdialog.h in Qt 4.8.5 network example w/ VS 2008

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

I am new to developing with Qt and I wish to compile the Qt network chat example that comes with Qt 4.8.5: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-network-chat.html

I'm working within VS 2012 but compiling with VS 2008. I have the following includes:

```
C:\Qt\4.8.5\include\Qt;
C:\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtUiTools;
C:\Qt\4.8.5\include;
C:\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtCore;
C:\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtGui;
C:\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtNetwork;
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

I feel like there is some step I'm missing in the compilation process, perhaps something that generates the ui_chatdialog.h file? I can't figure out why it is missing from the example, and it does not exist in the files that came with the Qt version (4.8.5) that I downloaded.

This is my current output:

```
>------ Rebuild All started: Project: QTChatExample, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  chatdialog.cpp
1>c:\users\dustin\documents\qtchatexample\src\chatdialog.h(44): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ui_chatdialog.h': No such file or directory
1>  client.cpp
1>  connection.cpp
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\dustin\documents\qtchatexample\src\chatdialog.h(44): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ui_chatdialog.h': No such file or directory
1>  peermanager.cpp
1>  server.cpp
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run uic to generate the header files for your ui files

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/uic.html

and also you need moc to generate your source meta-object code for things like signals and slots.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html

One way to do this is to use the Qt addon for Visual Studio. Although you could create a custom build step that executes moc, uic and the resource compiler or use QMake or CMake which will also execute these for you.

http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/what_is_the_qt_visual_studio_add-in

Since you also tagged this question for VS2012 I will add the following:

[Is it possible to work with Qt4 projects in Visual Studio 2012 using add-ins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221812/is-it-possible-to-work-qt4-projects-in-visual-studio-2012-using-add-ins)

Comment: you can use the addin v1.2.2 to use Qt4 in Visual Studio 2012, see answer to the linked question